# How to stop a timer from counting when a Javascript memory game finishes?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a question on how to stop the timer in a "find the pair" game, built in javascript for a school project.

While trying to look for help online I noticed other javascript projects for a similar game.
However, the ones I found had more use of CSS functionalities, while the one I am trying to finish has practically all the functionalities built in javascript.

To give a description, there is a board (6x8) with random logos, let's call them 'cards'.
The game starts and all the cards are sorted randomly and then hidden.

For 60 seconds all the cards remain in the same position while the player tries to match them.
After that time, only the cards that have not been paired are sorted again, and the player will have to try to pair them again.

One of the things that the code must do is to stop the time when all the cards are correctly paired, i.e. when the game is finished.

Below there is the last version of the code made to end the game.
The function tempo() is supposed to define the time.
The temporizador is the time progress bar.
The contador is the variable used to count the time.

```
function tempo(){       //function that controls our time progress bar, uses 60 seconds (maxCount) for its cycle
    let contador=0;     
    let maxCount=60;
     temporizador=null;
    if (temporizador != null) clearInterval(temporizador)   
    else 
    temporizador=setInterval(()=>{
        contador++;
        document.getElementById("time").value=contador;
        if(contador===maxCount-5)document.getElementById("time").classList.add("warning");  //when it takes 5 seconds to end the 60 seconds
        if(contador===maxCount) {                                                           //in the time bar, you can see the bar in red, blinking
            clearInterval(temporizador);                                                    
            document.getElementById("time").classList.remove("warning");                    //when cycle finished the red blinking stops
            scramblerEscondidas();                                                          //and the function scramblerEscondidas() to sort the unmatched pairs, is executed
        }                                                                                   
    },1000)
    for (let i=0; i<6; i++) {              //cycle to iterate the rows of the board
        for(let j=0; j<8; j++){            //cycle to iterate the columns of the board
            if (game.board[i][j].virada=true) tempo.stop();  //'virada' is a property of each card of the board, if true it displays the logo. defined in the 'const' for the card
                game.sounds.win.play();
        }

    }
    
}
```

The last cycle for in this function is supposed to check if all the cards are turned to the player, meaning the game is finished.
It is supposed to stop the time (the progress in the time bar) when this happens, but the timer doesn't stop.

Sorry for my noobness. Can anyone give any tips on how to find a solution for this?
I also tried different approaches but I fear they all used the same logic, which is likely faulty.
Any simple tip would help as I just recently started using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see what are you trying to do with these code.
But I got your point in stopping the timer.

To make a timer stop, you just have to make a boolean variable called `isHaveWinner` set it with with default **false** value.
Then wrap your counter function with

```js
if (!isHaveWinner) {
  ...your timer iteration
}
```

In your game logic, if the game finished set the `isHaveWinner` to **true**. So your timer won't run no more